# Nginx: Tags in Syslog output on wrong position

Tags: nginx, freebsd, syslog, jail

I'm trying to output the logs of several Nginx servers in FreeBSD jails to the jails' host.
I'm using FreeBSD 10 syslog and Nginx 1.7.10.

In Nginx (in this case the hostname is `web`) I have set:

```
access_log syslog:server=127.0.0.1:514 syslog;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html

In the host's `syslog.conf`:

```
+web
*.=info                                          /var/log/jails/web/nginx-access.log
```

In the host's `rc.conf`:

```
syslogd_flags="-a 10.0.0.1/24:* -v -v -C"
```

the output in my file is

```
Mar 31 19:45:50 <local7.info> web web nginx: […]
```

My problem is that I would like to specify tags in Nginx to differentiate several servers.

According to the FreeBSD documentation of syslog.conf

> If a received message matches the specified facility and is of the speci-
>       fied level    (or a higher level), and the first word in the message after
>       the date matches the program, the action specified    in the action field
>       will be taken.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslog.conf&sektion=5

But my output is `hostname` `hostname` `tag / program`.

So trying to specify the program / a tag in `syslog.conf`(like `!nginx`) doesn't work.

Is there any way to catch tags on FreeBSD's syslog?
Is this a bug in Nginx 1.7.10?

Answer (score -1):

Nginx uses RFC 3164 to define its logging.

There's closed ticket for this issue. (and a link to a change)
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/677